# Room: performance of insert(Object) vs insert(List<Object>)

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

Does inserting object to database in the loop have lower performance than inserting list? I spent a lot of time to implement the insert(List) methods in my DAOs, but seems that I got less performance.

UPD. 
I implemented much more efficient packaging in lists, and insert(List)...get(List) methods shows more than 10x performance boost.
I used small lists of 2-5 objects, so I could not see the performance gain

Comment: "I spent a lot of time to implement the insert(List) methods" What did you do? It shouldn't be more than adding a method that takes a `List<>` or an array of your entities to the interface like in the example in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Insert or at most something that has an `@Transaction` annotation like in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction

Comment: @zapl I has Comment object, which contains DBComment entity, few DBUser entities, parent Comment object and other. Quite complex recursive structure. I must insert each child object. With insert(List) it's more complicated than insert(Obj)

Comment: I'm a kind of lost here... what are you implementing? the point of room is letting it implement the hard work for you.

Comment: @RaymondArteaga hard work for me is database design and querying =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

insert(List) will be better for performance than insert(Object).
When you call insert(Object) from inside a loop, a new transaction has to be started for each insertion. In the other hand, when you use insert(List), room initiates a single transaction and insert all the rows using that transaction. Try navigating to the generated code and read the implementations.

Comment: I thought Room could have a service for batch inserting single objects.

Comment: What's about `@Transaction`?

Answer (score 0):

### Huge difference with bulk insert, 30x speedup

In my case, I inserted 300 elements in a Transaction and then inserted 300 more with the ids of the first elements as a foreign key. First one by one then bulk (which added a bit of complexity upfront of course).

Doing it with bulk inserts like

```
@Insert
fun insertExamples(example: List<Example>): List<Long>//Id List
```

Made it go from around **1500ms to 50ms.**